# Semi-transparent colour layer over image?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to add a semi-transparent layer over an image using the `img` tag? I am also using bootstrap and trying to avoid using the `background-image` CSS solution because the tag offers a quick way to fill the parent div responsively.

**HTML**

```
<div id="homebackground">
   <div id="bgcont">
     <b-img id="fitfill" :src="require('../assets/homebg1.jpg')" fluid-grow alt="Responsive image"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bgcont{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  #fitfill{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  #homebackground{
    height: 91.5%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the css `::after` pseudo element:

```
#bgcont::after {
    content: ""; // ::before and ::after both require content
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Works great! Is there a reason why the transparent layer is covering some `div` elements that are children to a `div` right above `#homebackground`? I tried using `z-index` without any luck.

Comment: What z-index value did you try? Did you try a negative value. Hard to know what is going on because I can't see your css.

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. I went in a different direction and set the image in the body instead which got rid of many other issues. Thank you